# Prove the solution to a linear pde is 0 on an open unit ball

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

Given linear PDE $$x \cdot \nabla u +u=0$$ on a unit open ball, $u$ is $C^1$ on the ball and $C^0$ on the boundary, prove $u$ is $0$ on the unit ball.

I solved that $u$ is constant on the boundary, $u(0)=0$. I am thinking about using proof by contradiction and applying for the mean value theorem.

Comment: Hi there, your question as currently phrased is likely to attract close votes and downvotes, because it is a problem statement with no input of your own. To avoid this and also to get the best answers suited to your understanding, I suggest checking [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/)

Comment: I see, I solved that U is constant on the boundary, u(0)=0. I am thinking about using proof by contradiction and applying for the mean value thm.

Comment: Thank you, Calvin, it's my first time asking a question! Thank you for letting me know

Comment: I edited the question a little to include what your comments said, and will think about how to answer it later (need to leave for a bit, sorry and good luck!)

Comment: Thank you so much, Calvin. I couldn't appreciate it more :)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  I have tried to improve the readability of your question by my recent edit. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.  Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Answer (score 1):

This PDE can be solved using the method of characteristics. We first solve the PDE, and then deduce the claimed result.

### Solution of PDE

The characteristics $X$ are the solution to the parameterised ODE
$$ \partial_tX(x_0,t) = X(x_0,t), \\ X(x_0,0) = x_0$$
where $x_0$ ranges over the points in $\partial B_1(0)$ i.e. $|x_0|=1$. (we remark that $\partial B_1(0)$ is non-characteristic, i.e. none of the characteristics are tangent to it.)
The solution is
$$X(x_0,t) = x_0 e^t.$$

Lets say that on $\partial B_1(0)$, $u=g$ for some continuous function $g:\partial B_1(0)\to\mathbb R$. Setting $U(x_0,t):=u(X(x_0,t))$, we note that
$$ \partial_t U = ((\nabla u)\circ X)\cdot\partial_t X = X\cdot u(X) = -U$$
which gives
$$U(x_0,t) = g(x_0)e^{-t}.$$
$X$ has the inverse $(x_0(x),t(x)) =(\frac x{|x|} , \log |x|)$. so we can use this to write the solution as
$$u(x) = U(x_0(x),t(x)) =g\left(\frac x{|x|}\right) \frac1{|x|}$$
We can easily verify this factor of $\frac1{|x|}$ is correct: say $g\equiv 1$, i.e. $u(x)=\frac1{|x|}$ then
$$ \nabla u(x) = \frac{-x}{|x|^3} \implies x\cdot\nabla u(x) = \frac{-1}{|x|} = -u(x).$$

### Deducing that $u$ vanishes

Once we have the above form, it is easy to conclude. If the boundary data $g(x)=g_0\neq 0$ at any point $x$, then along the line joining $0$ to $x$, the solution takes the form $\frac{g_0}{|x|}$, which explodes as $x\to 0$. Since we assumed the solution to be continuous, this means $g$ must be identically zero.

However, from the form of $u$, this means that $u\equiv 0$.